# $[\frac{x}{2}] + [\frac{x}{3}] = \frac{5x}{6}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> **Question**: If $[\frac{x}{2}] + [\frac{x}{3}] = \frac{5x}{6}$, then $x$ is any of the following:
>   (a) $3,6,9,12,...$
>   (b) $9,18,27,36,...$
>   (c) $6,12,18,24,...$
>   (d) $\frac{6}{5},\frac{12}{5},\frac{18}{5},...$
>   **[.] represents the greatest integer function...**

*The solution is (c)*

My Attempt:

$$\frac{5x}{6} \in \mathbb{Z} \implies x=\frac{6n}{5}, n\in \mathbb{Z}$$
Substituting this value of x,
$$[\frac{3n}{5}]+[\frac{2n}{5}] = n$$
$$\implies \frac{3n}{5} - \{\frac{3n}{5}\} + \frac{2n}{5} - \{\frac{2n}{5}\} =n$$
$$\implies \{\frac{3n}{5}\}+\{\frac{2n}{5}\}=0$$
$\{.\}$ represents the fractional part function.

From here onwards, I don't know how to continue. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Hint: $[\dfrac x2]\le \dfrac x2$ and $[\dfrac x3]\le\dfrac x3$ with equality if and only if the quantities on the right hand side are integers. Also $(x/2)+(x/3)=5x/6$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I think that's an answer, and (at the moment) three other upvoters clearly think that it answers the question.

Comment: @rash You should use $\mathbb{Z}$ instead of $\mathbb{I}$ for the set of integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since fractional parts are non-negative, if two of them sum to $0$ they're each $0$. This tells us $2n/5,\,3n/5$ are integers, as is their difference $n/5$. This condition is clearly sufficient as well as necessary. But $5|n\iff 6|x$, confirming (c).